# How to maintain 16:9 aspect ratio of AppWindow when user resizes in Windows App SDK (WinUI 3)?

Tags: c#, windows, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

When a user resizes the main window in a WinUI 3 Windows App SDK app I would like to force the window to maintain an aspect ratio of 16:9. I tried to accomplish it in the SizeChanged event handler ...

```
private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
{
   var window = sender as MainWindow;
   Windows.Graphics.SizeInt32 y;
   y.Height = (int)args.Size.Height;
   int adjustedWidth = y.Height * 16 / 9;
   y.Width = adjustedWidth;
   window.AppWindow.Resize(y);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to use the underlying Windows API, as Windows is sending the [WM_SIZING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-sizing) message when a window is being resized.

For that, you need to be able to handle window messages. Here is some sample code, with interop parts, that does that:

```
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly WindowProcedureHook _hook;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        // hook the window procedure
        _hook = new WindowProcedureHook(this, WndProc);
    }

    private IntPtr? WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        // handle the WM_SIZING message
        const int WM_SIZING = 0x0214;
        if (msg == WM_SIZING)
        {
            // get sizing rect
            var rc = Marshal.PtrToStructure<RECT>(lParam);

            // if coming from left/right only, we adjust height
            const int WMSZ_LEFT = 1;
            const int WMSZ_RIGHT = 2;
            if (wParam.ToInt64() == WMSZ_LEFT || wParam.ToInt64() == WMSZ_RIGHT)
            {
                rc.height = rc.width * 9 / 16;
            }
            else
            {
                rc.width = rc.height * 16 / 9;
            }

            // put it back, say we handled it
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, lParam, false);
            return new IntPtr(1);
        }

        return null; // unhandled, let Windows do the job
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int left;
        public int top;
        public int right;
        public int bottom;

        public int width { get => right - left; set => right = left + value; }
        public int height { get => bottom - top; set => bottom = top + value; }
    }
}

// a utility class to hook window procedure and handle messages, or not
public sealed class WindowProcedureHook
{
    private readonly IntPtr _prevProc;
    private readonly WNDPROC _wndProc;
    private readonly Func<IntPtr, int, IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr?> _callback;

    public WindowProcedureHook(Window window, Func<IntPtr, int, IntPtr, IntPtr, IntPtr?> callback)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(window);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(callback);

        _wndProc = WndProc;
        var handle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
        _callback = callback;

        const int GWLP_WNDPROC = -4;
        _prevProc = GetWindowLong(handle, GWLP_WNDPROC);
        SetWindowLong(handle, GWLP_WNDPROC, Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(_wndProc));
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) => _callback(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam) ?? CallWindowProc(_prevProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    private delegate IntPtr WNDPROC(IntPtr handle, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr GetWindowLong(IntPtr handle, int index) =>
        IntPtr.Size == 8 ? GetWindowLongPtrW(handle, index) : (IntPtr)GetWindowLongW(handle, index);

    private static IntPtr SetWindowLong(IntPtr handle, int index, IntPtr newLong) =>
        IntPtr.Size == 8 ? SetWindowLongPtrW(handle, index, newLong) : (IntPtr)SetWindowLongW(handle, index, newLong.ToInt32());

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr CallWindowProc(IntPtr prevWndProc, IntPtr handle, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    // note: WinUI3 windows are unicode, so we only use the "W" versions

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtrW(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int GetWindowLongW(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLongW(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndexn, int dwNewLong);

    [DllImport("user32")]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowLongPtrW(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, IntPtr dwNewLong);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set both `Width` and `Height` on `SizeInt32`. This works:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.Graphics;

namespace WinUI3App1;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private double _currentWindowWidth = 0;

    private double _currentWindowHeight = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;
        KeepWindowSizeAspectRatio();
    }

    public double WindowSizeAspectRatio { get; set; } = 16.0 / 9;

    private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, WindowSizeChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        KeepWindowSizeAspectRatio();
    }

    private void KeepWindowSizeAspectRatio()
    {
        if (_currentWindowWidth is 0 ||
            _currentWindowHeight is 0)
        {
            _currentWindowWidth = this.AppWindow.Size.Width;
            _currentWindowHeight = this.AppWindow.Size.Height;
        }

        int newWidth = this.AppWindow.Size.Width;
        int newHeight = this.AppWindow.Size.Height;

        if (this.AppWindow.Size.Width != _currentWindowWidth)
        {
            newHeight = (int)(newWidth / WindowSizeAspectRatio);
            _currentWindowWidth = this.AppWindow.Size.Width;
        }

        if (this.AppWindow.Size.Height != _currentWindowHeight)
        {
            newWidth = (int)(newHeight * WindowSizeAspectRatio);
            _currentWindowHeight = this.AppWindow.Size.Height;
        }

        this.AppWindow.Resize(new SizeInt32(newWidth, newHeight));
    }
}
```

Comment: Works, but the window resize is not as smooth as with Simon's solution. Thanks!